# How does Uniswap's LowGasSafeMath work?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I'm having trouble understanding [LowGasSafeMath](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/LowGasSafeMath.sol).
For example, how does this function work?

```
function mul(uint256 x, uint256 y) internal pure returns (uint256 z) {
    require(x == 0 || (z = x * y) / x == y);
}
```

The first thing that puzzled me is that this returns a value without a return statement.
Then, how does the logic inside the require statement work? As a programmer, I'm familiar with boolean logic, but haven't seen it used like this before.

Comment: `require` statement is the equivalent to return from the entire application , or in other words `exit` so these statements are equivalent to C `assert`s

Comment: these statements are basically checking for the multiplication to overflow the 256 bit integer value. , the result of multiplication must be larger then the operands, thats what it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return is done with `returns (uint256 z)`.
This means that when the function ends the variable `z` is returned.
The function checks if there was an overflow in the multiplication, because then the result would be wrong. To make sure it is correct, the result of `z = x* y` is decided by `x`, if this equals `y` then the calculation is correct (one could also decide by `y`).
To avoid division by 0, it is checked if `x ==0`.
If this is the case, the whole statement is true and therefore not evaluated further.
Because multiplication by 0 is 0, no calculation is needed, because `z = 0` by default.

It is the same as

```
if (x==0) {
    return 0;
}
z = x * y;
require(z / x == y);
return z;
```